# apply colour change to only some tags

Tags: javascript, css

If I am using a `<h3>` tag and apply css

```
h3 {
  color:White;
}
```

changes the colour of all the header 3 text to white colour.
I only want to apply this to certain `<h3>` tags though among my many.
How can I do this please?

Comment: @John Did you want a JavaScript solution at all since you originally tagged the question with [tag:javascript]?

Comment: either way would suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them a class:

```
.white-header {
  color: white;
}
```

And in your html:

`<h3 class='white-header'>I m white</h3>`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0e45py2u/)

Comment: @Grundy yup yup it's there now, was making a fiddle.

Comment: Maybe better yet `h3.white-header`

Comment: You don't need that degree of specificity, unless he's setting styles on `h3` directly @MikkoViitala

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common class on them and use css for that.

> I only want to apply this to certain  tags though among my many.

Then you target parent element and apply css for that like below:

```
<h3>heading</h3>
<div class="foo">
   <h3>some heading</h3>
   <p>some paragraph</p>
</div>

h3{
  color: red;
}
.foo h3{/*applied for some heading*/
   color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is the way to go, but since the question is tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) here is a JS solution using [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to style select `<h3>` tags:

```
document.querySelector("div.someClass h3").style.color = "#FFF";
```

**Edit:** @Kitler just edited out the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag from the question. This answer is for the original question. If the OP leaves it off, then I will quietly delete this. Hold off before downvoting.